# What plant is this

Tags: identification

[image]

Does anyone know what plant this is? I got it from a local farmers market recently. I want to be able to find more information to know how best to care for it.

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be Hoya carnosa - I note one of the shoots is variegated, so possibly H. carnosa variegata, though there's either been some reversion to plain green, or those are two separate cuttings which have been rooted into the same pot. Their trailing habit means they are often grown in hanging pots - indoors they like bright daylight, but don't appreciate being in full sun all day, although some sun morning or evening is fine. Further info here https://www.joyusgarden.com/how-to-care-for-a-hoya-houseplant/ - scroll down for an image of H. carnosa variegata.